# RESTful LWRP / Library for Chef

Tags: rest, chef-infra, chef-solo, cookbook, lwrp

I need to be able to send REST calls and save the returning payload to variables within the cookbook (using chef solo).

- Calls are made in HTTPS
- Need to be able to get returning cookie header in order to login to API

Is there such a community LWRP available? I am not aware of any built-in functionality within chef to allow this. (from what I've read http_request provider in chef does not answer the above criteria)

Answer (score 1):

Resources (and thus LWRPs) don't really have output values. What you want is to just use [the `Chef::HTTP` class](https://coderanger.net/chef-tips/#4):

```
val = Chef::HTTP.new('https://cmdb/').get('/')
```

Comment: Thanks
I need to capture the returning cookie header - any idea on how to do that with the above approach?

Comment: The return value is a `Net::HTTP` response object.